# Proving $\left( 1-\frac{2}{n} \right )^{\frac {n\ln n}{4}}-\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )^{\frac {2n\ln n}{4}}<0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, asymptotics

As a part of a solution I'm writing I need to prove: $$\left( 1-\frac{2}{n} \right )^{\frac {n\ln n}{4}}-\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )^{\frac {2n\ln n}{4}}<0$$ for large enough $n$. I checked in Wolfram-Alpha and it looks like it's true.. I've tried using:

$$1-x\leq e^{-x}$$ and

$$1-x\geq e^{-2x}$$

but I get $$n^{-\frac {1}{2}}-n^{-1}>0$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint:
$$\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}{1-\frac{2}{n}}>1.$$
Thus, $$\left(\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}{1-\frac{2}{n}}\right)^{\frac{n\ln{n}}{4}}>1.$$

Comment: I've been hinted to use the above inequalities but they doesn't seem to work and your's nicer!

Comment: Small nit: if $n < e$, the $>$ would get inverted, correct? So we need $n >= e$ for this, correct?

Comment: @user1952500 I think it's true for all real $n>2$.

Comment: Sorry, completely my mistake, it should be as you say.